# Java is replacing '+' operator with ' ' while posting text to php url

Tags: java, php, post

I'm trying to post a string text which is random but it looks like this to my php file:

```
er2hZ+JL2BJDJHU7gPBBvU2pNXEmBdzWs2E5SAfMlssy62/FooDrCi/ajhCW412Q4nRjel+ezE2v
CS090Jhskg==
```

The string contains `+` operator, however, when java posts this to my php file, I get this as a response:

```
er2hZ JL2BJDJHU7gPBBvU2pNXEmBdzWs2E5SAfMlssy62/FooDrCi/ajhCW412Q4nRjel ezE2v
CS090Jhskg==
```

As you can see the `+` operator has been replaced with white space.

I used `DataOutputStream ps = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());` and `PrintStream` as well and both has the same problem. My java code is like this:

```java
try {
    // open a connection to the site
    URL url = new URL("http://www.yourdomain.com/yourphpscript.php");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    // activate the output
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());
    // send your parameters to your site
    ps.print("firstKey=Name+Contains+");

    // we have to get the input stream in order to actually send the request
    con.getInputStream();

    // close the print stream
    ps.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My php code is this:

```php
<?php 
    echo $_POST['firstKey'];
?>
```

This will return "Name Contains " '+' replaced with spaces.

Thanks for reading, and appreciate your help.

Comment: Conversion of `+` to space is a common effect of **URL decoding**. Your datastream is not causing the issue, but there is code somewhere that thinks the data is URL encoded and decodes it. Whether doing the decoding is wrong, or the lack of encoding upstream is wrong, is impossible to say with a lot more information.

Comment: URL decoding is probably the answer.  Off the top of my head, the only place where '+' should get decoded to a space is the query string.  So is this example part of a query string, or is it coming from somewhere else?  As Andreas says, we'll need more info.

Comment: the response coming from echo $message in my php file, nothing more than that. even if i send a string of "+++" it will come back as three spaces.

Comment: @I.PSARN - I think you are missing the point.  The cause of this is (most likely) how you are passing the string in the request.  You are passing a string that *requires* URL encoding without doing that. We need to see the Java-side code that is forming the request ... not just the stream declarations.

Comment: Have you tried setting header('Content-Type:text/plain'); in PHP to ensure there is no auto-detection happening somewhere and it's interpreted as URL.

Comment: I tried adding header('Content-Type:text/plain');  in my php header, did not work!

Comment: Stephen C, Thanks for your suggestion, I used  String encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8"); to do the job and it works nicely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bog-standard base64-encoded data is *not* URL-safe. At a minimum the characters `+` and `=` will cause problems.

You either need to use a URL-safe variant, for which you'll need to roll your own in PHP at least, or URL-encode the base64'd data.

In PHP this would look like:

```
$url = sprintf(
  'http://example.com/foo.php?data=%s',
  urlencode( base64_encode( $some_data ) )
);
```

Output: `http://example.com/foo.php?data=ZmFydGJhbGxzMQ%3D%3D`

Comment: Yea ... but he needs to do the encoding on the Java side.  The Question says that Java is POSTing to PHP, not the other way around.

Comment: @StephenC yeah, but I don't have any idea what the Java code would look like, and I mainly wanted to illustrate the general point. [feel free to duplicate my answer in Java] And even if it *is* POSTing using `x-www-form-urlencoded` it surprisingly expects the data to be properly urlencoded.

Comment: *"... but I don't have any idea what the Java code would look like ..."* and that's why we should >>wait<< until the OP posts his code.  There are lots of ways that the Java side could be forming requests.